# Access MainWindow title from a user control file

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How do I get the title of the main window `Title="Application Title"` but from another user control xaml file?

If I'm accessing the title from my main window xaml file then It would be `Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}"`, but when i try to do that from a separate user control xaml file it does not work.

[EDIT]

Here is the text block which needs to output the window title:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderText}" 
           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}"/>
```

And that's how I add my control in the mainwindow xaml file:

```
<local:TitlebarPanel Grid.Row="0">
</local:TitlebarPanel>
```

Comment: can you provide more code?

Comment: I've edited my comment. What more code would be needed tho?

Comment: Are you binding to a property in the code behind? or is this MVVM? If it's MVVM, why not bind the user control to the same property on the view model?

Comment: Actually what i made is initialize this

[Localizability(System.Windows.LocalizationCategory.Title)]
public string WindowTitle { get; set; } = "MyAppTitle";

And i just binded that to the window title and to the text block in my user control

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Title}"/>
```